# What is the "~/.stack" directory?

Tags: storage

My "~/.stack" directory is taking up 2.5GB and has the following main big directories :

```
1330    programs/
877     indices/
264     snapshots/
```

What is this "~/.stack" directory ?

Can I safely remove the biggest files in it ?

Comment: This directory seems to belong to haskell stack. It is up to you to decide if you still need it. No one else can tell you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/

> The stack root directory holds packages belonging to snapshots and any stack-installed versions of GHC.

You can safely remove any or all of it, but some of it might get replaced the next time you build Haskell programs using `stack`.  I'm surprised and somewhat annoyed by how big my `~/.stack` directory is too.